# iPhone 4S Message Display Format

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to display sent/received iMessages in a vertical format rather than the current left/right bubble formate?

Answer (score 1):

**No.** This is not something that is built into iOS.

There may be an option if you were to jailbreak your phone.